# Is there a Python function analog to MATLAB's "chol" which also returns the pivoting flag?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm porting a code from MATLAB to Python and, in some point, I need to use the Cholesky factorization function [`chol`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chol.html), but returning both the triangular matrix `R` and the pivoting `flag` (`0` if input is symmetric, positive definite and a non-zero value if the input is NOT symmetric positive definite, where the non-zero value is the index of the pivot position in which the factorization failed).

As far as I searched, I only found the NumPy function `numpy.linalg.cholesky`, but it only returns `R`.

Is there a way to return the value `flag`? Or, in any case, is there a function which returns both values, `R` and `flag`?

Comment: What does the Matlab function `chol` look like?

Comment: What Python version do you use?

Comment: @Robert Python 3.7.0

Comment: @3UqU57GnaX The syntaxis of the `chol` function is `[R,flag,P] = chol(S)`

Comment: If I am not mistaken you can open the function by typing `edit chol` in your workspace.

Comment: @3UqU57GnaX The problem is that my Matlab license expired, so I can't open Matlab.

Comment: I don't think there's an exact equivalent - if it's non positive definite you'll get an exception.